# Checking the TLS version in browser requests to https connection

Tags: https, openssl, network-protocols, transport-security

I want to check which `TLS` version client(Browser) is supporting currently.And which `TLS` version it wants to use. Is there any other way to check which `TLS` version  a particular browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all browsers can now support TLS 1.0.
Other versions of TLS 1.1 and 1.2 depend much more of your Browser and its version.

I will recommend you to keep staying with TLS 1.0 except if you really need one of the new features...

Answer (score 0):

"wants to use" is typically the highest level it supports, failing back to lower levels as each is denied or not available from the server.

Wikipedia has a table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers) that describes support for various browsers. I would recommend using the best that both browser and server support as a general rule.

If you have specific concerns perhaps a new question that describes those concerns and gives use cases would be a good way to find guidance.